# Why is gamlss fitting distributions which do not fit and are not feasible?

Tags: r, distributions, gamlss

I have the following example using `gamlss` to fit optimal distributions.

- z0 are random variables of normal distribution with mu=1 and sd=2.
- z1 should fit the best distribution: in my case it returns BCCG as best.
- z2 fits a normal distribution.
- z3 should fit the proposed BCCG, however this fails.

Why does this happen?

Further, if I plot the histogram, the proposed BCCG seems not to be the best fit.

Where did I go wrong?

```r
set.seed(123)
z0 <- rnorm(10000, 1, 2)
z1 <- gamlss::fitDist(z0, k=2, type="realAll", trace=FALSE, 
                      try.gamlss=TRUE)  # realplus | realAll
z1$fits
#  BCCG    BCCGo     BCTo      ...
# 22381.32 22381.32 22383.13   ...
z1$mu.coefficient; z1$mu.link
# [1] 0.9461219
# [1] "identity"
z1$sigma.coefficients; z1$sigma.link
# [1] 0.7571287
# [1] "log"

z2 <- gamlss(z0~1, family=NO)
z2$mu.coefficient; z2$mu.link
# (Intercept) 
#    1.023001 
# [1] "identity
z2$sigma.coefficients; z2$sigma.link
# (Intercept) 
#   0.6889655 
# [1] "log"

z3 <- gamlss(z0~1, family=BCCG)
# Error in gamlss(z0 ~ 1, family = BCCG) : response variable out of range

hist(z0)
hist(rBCCG(n=10000, mu=(z1$mu.coefficients), 
 sigma=exp(z1$sigma.coefficients)))
hist(rNO(n=10000, mu=(z2$mu.coefficients), 
 sigma=exp(z2$sigma.coefficients)))
```

Comment: Well, the distributions BCCG, BCCGo, BCPE etc. are only defined for positive values. By setting `type = "realAll"` you also try these distribution, which obviously aren't really appropriate here as you have negative values in `z0` as well. If you set `type = "realline"`, the normal distribution "wins", as expected.

Comment: Dear COOLSerdash,

thank you for the response. But I am still confused, as realline-distributions are a subset of realAll and I assumed that the best distribution - in this case the normal distribution - would be chosen from all distributions. Hence, distributions that are solely defined on R+ should be either automatically excluded or penalized to a greater extent, correct?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a good question why the ill-fitting distributions receive a lower GAIC than the approrpiate ones. I suspect that the algorithm simply doesn't converge or has problems otherwise. `fitDist` doesn't know what distributions to exclude or include based on the data alone. That task is relegated to the user. It doesn't seem good practice to me to even try statistical models that are known to be incompatible with the data.